# How to use tramp with corkscrew to access remote clusters?

Tags: emacs, ssh, http-proxy, tunneling

My computer network is closed to ssh to external machines (outside the network) through port 22. I have a round about by tunneling ssh through http by employing cockscrew. I modified my config file in the following fashion

```
Host EXTERNAL-HOSTNAME
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
ServerAliveCountMax=30
ServerAliveInterval=5
ProxyCommand corkscrew LOCAL-PROXYNAME PROXY-PORT-NO %h %p
```

How can I now use tramp to access the files in the remote cluster? The regular command `/ssh:username@EXTERNAL-HOSTNAME` fails to open the file.

**UPDATE 1:**

My proxy does not use the default 8080 port but a different port number. So using

```
/tunnel:PROXY-HOSTNAME PROXY-PORT-NO | ssh:USERNAME@EXTERNAL-HOSTNAME:~/
```

gave me the following error

> Tramp: Opening connection for tunnel using scp... Tramp: Sending
>   command `exec ssh   -o
>   ControlPath=/var/folders/k5/r4f1q8j90y345rsz_9skc7y48q0jr6/T/tramp.15685eSq.%r@%h:%p
>   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=no -e none tunnel' Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell... Tramp failed to connect.  If
>   this happens repeatedly, try`
>   M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection' Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed Tramp: Opening connection for tunnel using
>   scp...failed Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory
>   and its parents
>
> Tramp: Checking `vc-registered' for /tunnel:PROXY-HOSTNAME
>   PROXY-PORT-NO | ssh:USERNAME@EXTERNAL-HOSTNAME:~/...failed Use M-x
>   make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents Mark
>   set

**UPDATE 2:**

It worked. The only problem was I was not entering the port-no correctly. Now I just used

```
/tunnel:PROXY-HOSTNAME#PROXY-PORT-NO|ssh:USERNAME@EXTERNAL-HOSTNAME:~/
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know corkscrew so I cannot answer for this. However, Tramp is able to tunnel http by its own. Try to open `/tunnel:LOCAL-PROXYNAME|ssh:username@EXTERNAL-HOSTNAME`. The proxy command shall be removed from your ssh config, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still get an error  which I have updated in the question

Comment: In this case it might be simpler you send a Tramp bugreport via `M-x tramp-bug`. Please set `tramp-verbose` to 10 prior running the test, and add the resulting Tramp debug buffer to the bug report.